# $A$ is positive definite if and only if $Q$ is invertible for every choice of $Q$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Note that if $A \in M_{n \times n}$, $A^{\prime}$ denotes the transpose of $A$.

I proved the following theorem already:

> $A$ is nonnegative definite if and only if there exists a square
>   matrix $Q$ such that $A = QQ^{\prime}$.

Now I have to prove the following corollary:

> $A$ is positive definite if and only if $Q$ is invertible for every
>   choice of $Q$,

The book I have proves it. Here's what I gather from its proof after some rewording:

Suppose $Q$ is noninvertible. This is true if and only if $Q^{\prime}$ is noninvertible as well (since $\det(Q^\prime) = \det(Q) = 0$), and this is true if and only if there exists a $v \neq 0$, $v \in \mathbf{R}^n$, such that $Q^{\prime}v = 0$. Furthermore, $Q^{\prime}v = 0$ if and only if $v^{\prime}QQ^{\prime}v = v^{\prime}Av = 0$.

Now here's a question: how do I know that $A = QQ^{\prime}$ without assuming $A$ is positive definite, thus nonnegative definite, and then applying the theorem I already proved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof makes no assumption on the positive definiteness of $A$. It's constructing a matrix $A$ (which is nonnegative definite by the given theorem) from the non-invertible matrix $Q$, and showing that it turns out that $A$ is not positive definite, i.e. through a series of equivalence arguements, it says that

$Q$ is non-invertible $\iff QQ' =:A$ is not positive definite.

Comment: So basically, it's just:

Assume $Q$ is noninvertible. Then there exists $v \neq 0$ such that $Q^{\prime}v = 0$, or $v^{\prime}QQ^{\prime}v = 0$. Take $A = QQ^{\prime}$. Then $A$ is not positive definite.

Then use the contrapositive?

Comment: Yes, though I forgot to mention a detail: what is inferred is that $A$ is not positive definite, and $A$ is not negative definite either. This is where the theorem comes into play: negation tells you that either $A$ is positive definite, or $A$ is negative definite, but the theorem asserts that it can't be the latter.

Comment: How is this? Assume $Q$ is noninvertible, which is true if and only if there is $v \neq 0$ such that $Q^{\prime}v = 0$, or $v^{\prime}QQ^{\prime}v = 0$. Take $A = QQ^{\prime}$ so that $v^{\prime}Av = 0$. Equivalently, we have proven that $A$ satisfies $v^{\prime}Av \neq 0$ if and only if $Q$ is invertible.  By Theorem, $A = QQ^{\prime}$ if and only if $v^{\prime}Av \geq 0$, and since $v^{\prime}Av \neq 0$, $v^{\prime}Av > 0$, hence $A$ is positive definite.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what your confusion is. Are you referring to my last sentence?